# WebElement getText() Returns empty value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Following code is used to get a mobile phone's price from amazon using Selenium Webdriver.

1. If I use /span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnAZF.png) at end in xpath it is not printing anything
2. If I don't use xpath it prints price

HTML source code for the elements[image]

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.in");
    
    
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).sendKeys("one");
    
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    List<WebElement> all_mobile= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='suggestions']/div/span"));
    
    //Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    int total= all_mobile.size();
    
    //System.out.println(total);
    
    for(int i=0; i<total;i++)
    
    {
    
    String mobiles = all_mobile.get(i).getText();
    
    //System.out.println(mobiles);
    
    if(all_mobile.get(i).getText().equals("plus nord 5g"))
    
    {
    
    all_mobile.get(i).click();
    
    break;
    
    }
    
    }
    
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    String  text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@aria-label='FREE Delivery by Amazon'])[1]/span")).getText();
    
    System.out.println(text); //it prints FREE Delivery by Amazon working fine if I use /span at end or not both ways but below iam getting issue in price
    
    String  price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='a-price'])[1]/span[1]")).getText();
    
    System.out.println(price); //it prints nothing if iam using /span[1] at end   
    
    String  PRICE = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='a-price'])[1]")).getText();
    
    System.out.println(PRICE); //it prints ₹29,990 if iam not using /span[1] at end
```

Can anyone please help? Why I am getting different outputs with getText()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Price text is coming from the **second** span element. `<span aria-hidden="true">`. First span is hidden by CSS

```
<span class="a-price" data-a-size="l" data-a-color="price">
  <span class="a-offscreen">₹29,990</span>
  <span aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="a-price-symbol">₹</span>
    <span class="a-price-whole">29,990</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

You can get the price from the second span element too

```
 System.out.println("Experiments ");
 price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='a-price'])[1]/span[2]")).getText();
 System.out.println(price);
```

WebElement's getText() [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText()) shows that

> Get the visible (i.e. **not hidden by CSS**) text of this element, including sub-elements.

`<span class="a-offscreen">8888</span>` is hidden.

Comment: Hi if its hidden then how getText is working in this fashion : driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='a-price'])[1]")).getText();  //working fine if not using /span[1] at end please throw some light

Comment: Element located by driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='a-price'])[1]")) has two children. When you call getText() method it tries to get the text from both children and their children which are not hidden by CSS. Inner text from first child element is not returned as it is hidden by CSS class (a-offscreen). Hence text from second child element and it's sub elements are returned.

Comment: oohhh great didnot noticed that thanks  if I see <span class="a-offscreen">₹29,990</span>
  <span aria-hidden="true">